# Email Confirmation Showing Changes/DIFF to Record's + Association's Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assume I have an Order model that has many Order Line Items. I want to send an email after updating the Order that outlines any changed information.

**Order**

- ID
- PO Number
- Notes

**Order Line Item**

- ID
- Order ID
- Item Description
- Quantity

I researched and thought of many solutions. My best attempt was using ActiveRecord's "Dirty" methods in an Order's after_update callback in an each loop going over the attributes of both order and order line items and storing the changes in a hash and subsequently trying to loop through and display them in a user-friendly way in the email template. This quickly became very messy with LOTS of code. I deleted it out of frustration knowing there must be a better way.

Far easier would be to just send the in-memory instance of the updated Order model instance to the email so I could directly reference the "Dirty" attributes, but since I'm using "deliver_later", it washes away all of the *_before_last_save values.

One requirement I have is that the email template must show the record's values alongside the changed values.

Open to gems, but better to use native Rails functionality.

**Question - What is a clean, efficient approach to showing a diff of the order and line items in an email while using deliver_later?**

Comment: paper_trail will get your changes wrapped up nicely -- https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail. Then you can just use the changes to supply the email.

Comment: I did think of this too! I think this would work, it just seems like a heavy solution for a small application. I actually have the paper trail gem in my app already being used elsewhere. I wanted to know if anyone could think of a good way to do this just using DIRTY methods after_update.